# Is this way of making an XNA game window borderless safe to use for various Windows PCs?

Tags: xna, window-management

I have found a [way to simply make an XNA 4.0 game's window borderless](http://lukecapizano.blogspot.com/2012/09/want-to-display-borderless-window-in-xna.html). Here is the code from the article:

```
IntPtr hWnd = this.Window.Handle;
var control = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle( hWnd );
var form = control.FindForm();
form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
form.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

You add it to the Game's constructor and it works perfectly. I tested it on several Windows PCs and it's great: the game runs seemingly in full screen, even if you set the game's resolution lower/higher than your desktop one. The only issue I had with it is the fact that you need to provide positions for XNA's SpriteBatch methods (Draw and DrawString) in desktop resolution, not in game's resolution, while retrieving width/height from GraphicsDevice gives you the latter.

At the same time, DOTA 2 has borderless window option, but the game scales the window down, if your requested in-game resolution is lower than your desktop one. I wonder if they have a good reason for doing this?

I wanted to ask if this approach is safe to use on PC or can it be buggy occasionally? I would especially like to know if it will work with Windows XP as I don't have a pc with this system to test it.

Comment: I don't use XNA, but that's the way to do it in plain Direct3D (both pre-9 and 10+). However, XP is no longer supported: you might want to consider not including XP support to your game, as it creates an additional testing burden, and most people who play games are using 7 or newer anyways... (this statistic I just pulled out of nowhere, feel free to disagree)

Comment: Thanks @PandaPajama, is there a way in C# to test what system is installed on the client's PC? That way I would be able to lock this option for XP users.

Comment: Mostly `System.Environment.OSVersion`, but that's outside the scope of this question. Google is your friend. However, disabling something because you suppose that it might not work on XP (it most likely will though) may be a bit overkill. If you really need to support XP, you should probably actually support it. If you're just being halfhearted about XP support, you might want to consider simply not supporting it.

Comment: Why would you need this functionality in the first place?

Comment: @PetrAbdulin borderless window is a pretty badass feature as it looks like fullscreen mode and folds/unfolds as fast as in windowed mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
form.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

The MSDN documentation does a good job of listing the platforms supported for each function.

### [form.FormBorderStyle MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Platforms
>
> Windows 7, Windows Vista SP1 or later, Windows XP SP3, Windows XP SP2 x64 Edition, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core supported with SP1 or later), Windows Server 2003 SP2

### [form.WindowState MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formwindowstate(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Platforms
>
> Windows 7, Windows Vista SP1 or later, Windows XP SP3, Windows XP SP2 x64 Edition, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core supported with SP1 or later), Windows Server 2003 SP2

Comment: Looks like the answer was not trivial, I did not know MSDN lists versions for each function, thanks!

Comment: This platforms list is for .NET 4.5, it's not relevant to XNA.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a basic function, it should be safe, but you should look into setting up a VM or finding a friend with an XP machine so that you can specifically test for it.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is pretty basic for Win32 API, you are pretty safe to use it on XP (and even below).

The OS support for `FormBorderStyle` enumeration (on .NET 3.5), [for example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP SP2, Windows XP Media Center
>   Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows XP Starter
>   Edition, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server
>   2003, Windows Server 2000 SP4, Windows Millennium Edition, Windows 98,
>   Windows CE, Windows Mobile for Smartphone, Windows Mobile for Pocket
>   PC

same goes for `FormWindowState`. I hope that edit makes answer more useful.

Comment: Note, some people have flagged this for content and length issues. [sarcasm]You should add surplus text to say the same thing in more words because yeah.[/sarcasm] (On a more serious note, I don't know if the answer is correct, but I know it's a valid answer, I don't find its length to be an issue.)

Comment: I would add: [sarcasm]you should add surplus text because f**k yeah![/sarcasm]

Comment: I would assume people flagged it because "Yeah I think you're good" is a poor answer.